# Anypoint Studio automatically adding /ee to XMLNS paths

Tags: xml, mule, mule-studio

So I inherited a project that is built using Mulesoft. I've spent a good amount of time trying to debug why my seemingly simple changes aren't working, only to realize my XML file is being changed when I try and save it.

I'm using Anypoint Studio and modifying an existing flow. What happens is when I save, for some reason it's updating the  tag

Before Save:

```
<mule xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
        xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
    xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    version="CE-3.6.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp/current/mule-ftp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">
```

After Save:

```
<mule xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
        xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
    xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    version="CE-3.6.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp/current/mule-ftp-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">
```

As you can see it's trying to add "Enterprise Edition" (mule/ee/ftp) to my FTP tags automatically when i save.

How do I stop this?

Comment: What is the default runtime on your Mule project? Is it an EE runtime by any chance?

Comment: @DavidDossot I'm not entirely sure how to check that. The biggest issue I've got right now is I've never worked with Mule and everyone who has no longer works here.

If it's not a special place to configure it for mule, then it's just set to the plain old 1.7 JDK.

Comment: @DavidDossot Ahh, did some digging in every menu I could find, and it is indeed. "Deafult Runtime selection : Mule Server 3.6.0 EE" 

Which lead me to here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Adding+Community+Runtime#AddingCommunityRuntime-AddingCommunityRuntime

and that seems to have fixed it! You led me on the right path, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have selected a `CE` runtime for your project in Studio.

- Double-click `mule-project.xml` at the root of the project,
- Select a CE Runtime, as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

David Dossot mentioned in a comment that lead me on the way to finding the solution.

The issue was I was set to use the "Mule Server 3.6.0 EE" runtime by default on my Anypoint Studio installation. (Windows > Preferences > Anypoint Studio)

Installing a new runtime and setting it as my Default fixed the issue.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Adding+Community+Runtime#AddingCommunityRuntime-AddingCommunityRuntime

Comment: Argl you've beat me to it, posted my answer at the same time :$

Comment: Hey no worries, thanks a ton for your help! I was completely stuck.